# Inner join within Common Table Expression in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have table "table1", which contain following rows:

```
ColA    ColB
-------------
 p4      x1
 p4      z
 p4      z
 p5      s
 p5      t
 p5      y1
 p8      x1
 p8      y1
 p8      x1
 p9      x1
 p10     z1
 p1      z1
 p2      z1
 p3      z1
```

Now I need to display a table like this:(As expected)

```
ColA    ColB    Result
----------------------
 p4      x1       0
 p8      x1       0
 p9      x1       0
 p5      y1       0
 p8      y1       0
 p1      z1       0
 p10     z1       0
 p2      z1       0
 p3      z1       0
```

For which i am writing query:

```
with cte 
as
(
    select colb,cola,dense_rank() over(partition by colb order by cola asc) tem
    from table1
)
select s.cola, s.colb, 0 as result into tem_table
from table1 s
inner join cte c on c.colb = s.colb
where tem > 1
group by s.cola,s.colb
order by s.colb;
```

But I dont want to use inner join in the above query because of low perfromance. So I am trying query:

```
with cte as 
(
    select colb,cola,dense_rank() over(partition by colb order by cola asc) tem
    from table1
) 
select cola,colb,0 as result into tem_table from cte
where tem > 1 
group by cola,colb 
order by colb;
```

This gives an output:(Which is not correct)

```
ColA    ColB    Result
----------------------
 p8      x1      0      
 p9      x1      0
 p8      y1      0
 p10     z1      0
 p2      z1      0
 p3      z1      0
```

How can get the expected output without using inner join in CTE because it is self joining an getting
more time to execute.

Comment: I can't understand the logic behind your resultset. You have 3 records with `colA = p5`, why you are choosing the one with `colB = y1`? Is `result` a fixed constant?

Comment: I want to choose colb values which belongs to cola values greater then one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  colA, colB, 0
FROM    (
        SELECT  colA, colB, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY colB) cnt
        FROM    (
                SELECT  DISTINCT colA, colB
                FROM    mytable
                ) q
        ) q
WHERE   cnt > 1
```